# Install4j ServiceException during "stop a service" action

Tags: install4j

Our uninstaller has to remove a windows service that was installed. Sometimes this action "stop a service" throws an error:

[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.services.StopServiceAction [ID 1194]: ServiceException{errorCode=5001}

What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the service did not shut down within the maximum shutdown time, typically 20 seconds.

To increase that shutdown time, see

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/146092

Comment: Is it somehow possible to tell Install4j to wait until the service is really stopped?

Comment: Unfortunately not. It's not install4j that is terminating the shutdown, but Windows itself.